# Do matrices commutate under self multiplication?

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have any matrix $A$, then $A^n = A.A^{n-1} = A^{n-1}.A$

Will this hold for any matrix $A$ or do we have to have some restrictions on matrix $A$?

More generally, is this true-

$A^{n+m} = A^n.A^m = A^m.A^n$

for any matrix $A$?

Comment: Yes it holds for any matrix.

Comment: Matrice multiplication is associative. This means that you are correct. Please have a look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_associativity) is the term you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to find $A^2$ we need $A$ to be a square matrix that is $n\times n $ matrix.

If the matrix is a square matrix, then the multiplication of powers of $A$ is commutative and $$A^{n+m} = A^n.A^m = A^m.A^n$$